# Find OU in which a server exists using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Can some one help me out to find an OU in which the computer account exists using powershell? without using the quest AD commandlets i mean someting using [ADSI]

Thanks
Vinith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$computerName = "DC1"
$found = $FALSE
$domain = [ADSI]("LDAP://dc=contoso,dc=com")

$ous = ($domain.psbase.children |
        Where-Object {$_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "OrganizationalUnit"} |
        Select-Object -expand Name)        

foreach ($child in $ous){
    $ou = [ADSI]("LDAP://ou=$child,dc=contoso,dc=com")
    $computers = ($ou.psbase.children |
                  Where-Object {$_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "Computer"} |
                  Select-Object -expand Name)

    foreach ($client in $computers){
        if ($client -eq $computerName) {
            Write-Host "Found $computerName in" $ou.psBase.name
            $found = $TRUE
        }
    }
}

if (-not $found) {Write-Host "$computerName not found."}
```

You'd have to modify it if your clients are in nested OUs.

Comment: hi louis, it alwas returns computer not found!

Comment: hi louis.. im still unable to get out the child ou information from $ou.psbase.children, can you please help me out with the code modification...

Comment: yes i did read your last line.. hmm im an intermediate level in AD scripting :) so wanted your help for the same :) thanks vinith.

Comment: hi @louis can you please help me out. Thanks